# Should I make all the Getter, Setter property type string?

Tags: c#

I have student class:

```
        string name;
        double gpa;
        
        internal string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                if (value.All(c => !char.IsDigit(c) || char.IsWhiteSpace(c)) && value.Length > 0)
                {
                    name = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Student's name is not valid");
                }
            }
        }

        internal string GPA
        {
            get { return gpa.ToString(); }
            set
            {
                if (double.TryParse(value, out double n) && Convert.ToDouble(value) >= 0 && Convert.ToDouble(value) <= 10)
                {
                    gpa = Convert.ToDouble(value);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Student's GPA is not valid");
                }
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Student's name: {Name}\nStudent's GPA {GPA}";
        }
    }
```

And my main class:

```
            Student student = new Student();
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter student's name: ");
                    student.Name = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter student's GPA: ");
                    student.GPA = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(student.ToString());
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
```

I do all validation in getter and setter even the input format validation for gpa property, in order to do that I have to make the GPA string, I'm new to programming and I think this makes the code cleaner, but I don't see anyone do this so there must be some problem, is this bad practice?, should I make the GPA double and do the input format validation in main.

Comment: if `GPA` is expected to be `double` then use double property, and not string. In general, All validations, conversions, and other processing would be outside the getters/setters. You could use methods, or classes. However, in your case you will need a validation class for student, to validate user input and convert it to the target type if necessary.

Comment: Generally the data types you use should be the correct type for the data. We only really involve strings when we want to format them for the user, read input from the user, or sometimes when send/receiving them. Even when talking to a database, they should not be strings.

Comment: Instead of just throwing a `new Exception`, try to refine it a bit better.  For example `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is more suitable. This way you don't have to `catch (Exception exception)` this is too broad. whenever IOExceptions etc.. can be handled on another level.

Comment: That Student class should only be concerned about *storing* data, not validating user input. What if you have a list of students and want to filter all that have a GPA above a certain value? Hard with a string value, easy with a double.